# Sorting multiple ranges separated by empty cells

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to Excel programming, and need some help creating a macro that can define multiple ranges, separated by empty cells, and sort each range separately. This may have up to 250 separate ranges, and would need to only sort numbers in each contiguous section, leaving the text headers at the top of each section.

Comment: I would add one more column add a group id. Then do sort on all using carefully planned sort hierarchy. If you really must, write macro to insert blank rows between groups after the fact. Keep it simple.

Comment: If you can figure out how to do it manually, then you can use the Record Macro button in the Developer tab to write the code for you. Otherwise there is no way for us to guess exactly what you are trying to achieve without any sample input, output, and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare range variables and then set these range variables equal to the cells you want:

```
Dim rRange1 as Range
Set rRange1 = range(cells(row1, col1), cells(row2, col2))
```

Then you can use the sort property to sort as you wanted with headers.

You would then plug that into a loop so you wouldn't have to do it manually for each range.